# Get code for Opportunistic routing in ns2

Tags: omnet++, ns2

I want to simulate opportunistic routing protocol in ns2 . Does anyone know where can I get the code or atleast some reference to write code. I searched it but didn't find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally opportunistic routing algorithm (TORA) is present in e.g. ns-2.35/. But the default code isn't working very well. I.e. in order not to conflict with other protocols, the functions are limited to a minimum.

A working TORA can be added with "tora_ns235-1.patch" 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNWXc4UnRYcGVHZXc/view?usp=sharing

```
$ tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz     # year 2014 update
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

```
$ cd ns-allinone-2.35/
$ patch -p0 < tora_ns235-1.patch
$ ./install
$ cd ns-2.35/
$ cp ns ns235-tora         # This is also your backup
$ sudo cp ns235-tora /usr/local/bin/

------- Simulation -----------
$ ns235-tora 02-T-msg12973.tcl
```

Tora-examples_06.19.tar.gz 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1INSqfrCCw7xZk_PTgtEkK-7Rw7kg5-2A/view?usp=sharing